# Subset dataframe: taking previous value from the original df but not in the subset

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like the following:

```
                        A
2018-10-16 15:11:00     100
2018-10-16 15:11:07     101
2018-10-16 15:11:11     102
2018-10-16 15:11:12     101
2018-10-16 15:11:13     100
2018-10-16 15:11:17     110
2018-10-16 15:11:20     103
2018-10-16 15:11:41     99
2018-10-16 15:11:54     107
```

And a subset dataframe like the following:

```
                        A
2018-10-16 15:11:11     102
2018-10-16 15:11:20     103
2018-10-16 15:11:41     99
```

I need to convert it to the following:

```
                        A       New
2018-10-16 15:11:11     102     101
2018-10-16 15:11:20     103     110
2018-10-16 15:11:41     99      110
```

That is: for each row, take the previous value in the original dataframe but not in the subset dataframe

Comment: Last `110` is correct? Because previous value is `103`

Comment: It is correct. Because the previous (2018-10-16 15:11:20)  is in the subset dataframe too. So the correct value is the one from 2018-10-16 15:11:17 that is not in the subset df

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally made that way:

df:

```
    A
1   1000
2   1000
3   1001
4   1001
5   10
6   1000
7   1010
8   9
9   100000
10  6
11  999
12  10110
13  10111
14  1000
```

subnet_df:

```
    A
5   10
8   9
9   100000
10  6
12  10110
13  10111
```

.

```
subnet_indexs = subnet_df.index
aux_df = df.copy()
aux_df['NEW'] = aux_df['A']
aux_df.loc[subnet_indexs, new_column_name] = np.nan
aux_df[new_column_name].fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)
subnet_df = aux_df.loc[subnet_indexs]
```

.

```
    A       NEW
5   10      1001.0
8   9       1010.0
9   100000  1010.0
10  6       1010.0
12  10110   999.0
13  10111   999.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) by index values with default outer join and [`DataFrame.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html)ed original values, then replace matched values to missing and forward filling them, last remove rows by missing values by `A` column:

```
df = pd.concat([df_subset['A'], df['A'].shift()], axis=1, keys=('A','new'), sort=True)
df['new'] = df['new'].mask(df['new'].isin(df['A'])).ffill()
df = df.dropna(subset=['A'])
print (df)
                         A    new
2018-10-16 15:11:11  102.0  101.0
2018-10-16 15:11:20  103.0  110.0
2018-10-16 15:11:41   99.0  110.0
```

Comment: the 2018-10-16 15:11:41 value must be 110. Not 103

Comment: @Alfonso_MA - Can you explain more?